# How to catch all PHP errors?

Tags: php, error-handling

I need a solution to catch all PHP fatal errors, exceptions, warnings, etc. and have a callback.

I want to display a friendly version of the error to the user and log that error.

I'm thinking about using a text file per day for logging error.

Any suggestion or PHP class (library)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

php method: [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) might be what you are looking for.

More at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

and at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php

Answer (score 23):

As of PHP 8 the best way to catch any and all Exceptions is to catch the [Throwable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) interface which "is the base interface for any object that can be thrown via a throw statement". So your code would look something like this.

```php
try {
    # code...
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    # code...
}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, thanks!

Comment: For some reason, bzopen don´t throws  a Throable

Answer (score 19):

This makes almost all errors become catchable instance of `ErrorException`:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ){
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
});
```

use it before of the code that can give errors, for instances at the very top of your php file or in a common header included

*Limits*: **Severest** errors (PHP engine, server, syntax) cannot be handled with a user defined function: `E_ERROR`, `E_PARSE`, `E_CORE_ERROR`, `E_CORE_WARNING`, `E_COMPILE_ERROR`, `E_COMPILE_WARNING`, and most of `E_STRICT` raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called compromise it.

But, if syntax is correct and server don't broke, these errors should not appear.

If needed, you could workaround it with the `register_shutdown_function()` and `error_get_last()`

Comment: Note that not all PHP errors can be handled with a user-defined error handler using `set_error_handler`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527894/set-error-handler-doenst-work-for-fatal-error#answer-8527924

Answer (score 9):

Try launch this web page, you should see "Message: Division by Zero".

```
// Set Error Handler

set_error_handler (
    function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
        throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);     
    }
);

// Trigger an exception in a try block

try {
    $a = 3/0;
    echo $a;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I quite like the error handling from the kohana framework. You'd have to do a bit of work to pull it out though.

http://kohanaframework.org/

It will allow you to do error logging to a file and email a recipient. It also enables you to redirect to your friendly error page.