# Get all PHP errors/warnings/... that occurred during the current request

Tags: php, error-handling

Setting the directive `display_errors` to `true` (while having `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL`) prints all errors that occured during the current request bofore returing the PHP output.

Since I'm sending headers in my PHP code, I get several more errors (sending header after content has been sent is not possible).

Now I'd like to add the error messages to the end of my page. There I'd like to show all errors that occurred (until then). Unfortunately [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) only returns the last error that occurred.

I first thought that [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) might solve the problem, but I'm afraid that my error-logging does not work anymore:

> It is important to remember that the standard PHP error handler is completely bypassed for the error types specified by error_types unless the callback function returns FALSE.

Besides that:

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.

But maybe they are also not available in `error_get_last()`

**So is there a way to print all errors after the output of the generated content?**

Comment: Is it not possible to write/append error information into a error log file and then just read it out later on?

Comment: How I wish all errors were exceptions in PHP...

Comment: @SparK: You can try http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php#112881 ; but I agree: error handling like in Java would be nice,...

Comment: @vaultboy: That's HDD I/O - and that's considered to be slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Referring to your **first concern**

The error handling will still work as long as the:

> callback function returns FALSE

```
function myErrorHandler($error_level, $error_message, $error_file, $error_line, $error_context) {
    // Do your stuff here, e.g. saving messages to an array

    // Tell PHP to also run its error handler
    return false;
}
```

One solution to store all error-numbers (in an outside array `$error_list`) could be:

```
$error_list = array();

$myErrorHandler = function ($error_level, $error_message, $error_file, $error_line, $error_context) use (&$error_list) {
    $error_list[] = $error_level;
    // Tell PHP to also run its error handler
    return false;
};
// Set your own error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler($myErrorHandler);
```

Another approach is to use Exceptions. There is a nice example in the comments for the [function set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php#112881)

Also see:

- [Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)
- [PHP: Callback function using variables calculated outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588714/php-callback-function-using-variables-calculated-outside-of-it)

## Referring to your **second concern**:

As `Egg` already mentioned: using `register_shutdown_function()` is a way to go, and the code in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313887/771077 shows you how.

But keep in mind, that

- Registering the shutdown- and error-handling functions should be the first thing in code (I fool once had an error in a config file, which was not handled correct, since I registered the error handler afterwards).
- Parse errors might not be handled correctly (See comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313887/771077)

Comment: Could you expand your code by also getting  fatal errors,...that was proposed `Egg`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527894/set-error-handler-doenst-work-for-fatal-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900208/php-custom-error-handler-handling-parse-fatal-errors) (amongst others), with the [second answer on the latter list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313887) using a mix of `set_error_handler()` with `register_shutdown_function()` being a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Fuller example that catches all the errors (exceptions and errors), pumps to a log file and remembers in a static class; at the end you query the static class to get the error.

I use similar to this for all projects to get full control over all errors.

```
function customErrorHandler($errno, $errmsg, $filename, $linenum, $vars) {
    ErrorHandler($errno, $errmsg, $filename, $linenum, $vars, true);
}

function nullErrorHandler($errno, $errmsg, $filename, $linenum, $vars) {
    ErrorHandler($errno, $errmsg, $filename, $linenum, $vars, false);
}

function customExceptionHandler($exception) {
    if (is_a($exception, 'exceptionError')) {
        echo $exception->output();
    } else {
        ErrorHandler(E_ERROR, $exception->getMessage() . '(' . $exception->getCode() . ')', $exception->getFile(), $exception->getLine(), null, true);
    }
}

function nullExceptionHandler($exception) {
    if (is_subclass_of($exception, 'exceptionError')) {
        $exception->output();
    } else {
        ErrorHandler(E_WARNING, $exception->getMessage() . '(' . $exception->getCode() . ')', $exception->getFile(), $exception->getLine(), null, false);
    }
}


function ErrorHandler($errno, $errmsg, $filename, $linenum, $vars, $fatal) {
    $errortype = array (
            E_ERROR              => 'Error',
            E_WARNING            => 'Warning',
            E_PARSE              => 'Parsing Error',
            E_NOTICE             => 'Notice',
            E_CORE_ERROR         => 'Core Error',
            E_CORE_WARNING       => 'Core Warning',
            E_COMPILE_ERROR      => 'Compile Error',
            E_COMPILE_WARNING    => 'Compile Warning',
            E_DEPRECATED         => 'Deprecated',
            E_USER_ERROR         => 'User Error',
            E_USER_WARNING       => 'User Warning',
            E_USER_NOTICE        => 'User Notice',
            E_USER_DEPRECATED    => 'User Deprecated',
            E_STRICT             => 'Runtime Notice',
            E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  => 'Catchable Fatal Error'
            );


    // Pushed into error log
    if (error_reporting() > 0) {
        $message = ': ' . $errmsg . ' in ' . $filename . ' on line ' . $linenum;
        error_log('PHP ' . $errortype[$errno] . $message);

        errorLogger::log($message);

        if ($fatal) {
            echo $errortype[$errno] . ': ' . $message;
            exit();
        }
    }
}


class errorLogger {

    private static $aErrors = array();

    // ******************* Timing functions *********************************

    public static function log($message) {
        self::$aErrors[] = $message;
    }

    public static function getErrors() {
        return self::$aErrors;
    }

}
```

Usage Example

```
// Custom error handler. Can cope with the various call mechanisms
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler('nullErrorHandler');
$old_exception_handler = set_exception_handler('nullExceptionHandler');

// Do your stuff
// *
// *
// *
// *
// *

$old_error_handler = set_error_handler('customErrorHandler');   // Set to 'nullErrorHandler' to allow it to continue
$old_exception_handler = set_exception_handler('customExceptionHandler');   // Set to 'nullExceptionHandler' to allow it to continue

// At end
$errors = errorLogger::getErrors();
foreach($errors as $errorMessage) {
    echo $errorMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch the errors as you go and output messages at the end.

```
<?php 
$errors = [];
try{    
  // code to test
} catch(\Exception $e) {
  $errors[] = $e->getMessage;
}
try{    
  // next bit of code to test
} catch(\Exception $e) {
  $errors[] = $e->getMessage;
}
...

// display all messages at the end
echo "\n<pre><code>\n";
print_r($errors);
echo "\n</code></pre>\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

  or
   set your php.ini with this line:
   display_errors=on
```