# why in php I am getting _default error message along with custom error message i set with set_error_handler

Tags: php

why also getting default error handler message with custom one which i setted with set_error_handler here is my code below

```
     function custom_handler($error_level,$error_message){
 echo   "[$error_level] $error_message";
}

set_error_handler("custom_handler",E_WARNING);
require_once('try.php')
```

and here is the output

> "[2] require_once(try.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'try.php' (include_path='D:\software\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   D:\software\xampp\htdocs\samples\code.php on line 14"

Comment: If I remember correctly (and not out of date) set_error_handler doesn't deal with fatal errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set\_error\_handler() doens't work for FATAL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527894/set-error-handler-doenst-work-for-fatal-error)

Answer (score 1):

As per php manual:

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also
>   produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error. In other words, it will
>   halt the script whereas include only emits a warning (E_WARNING) which
>   allows the script to continue.

and

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined
>   function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING,
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the
>   file where set_error_handler() is called.

Your custom handler is showing the E_WARNING, the default handler is showing the E_COMPILE_ERROR.