Empty page PHP8.3 instead of error message output
The following code has a problem with the access level of $bla.
Normally I would expect the error output "Fatal error: Access level to mySlave::$bla must be public (as in class myMaster)". But my page is just empty/white althoug all error reporting is activated.
I have this on two different systems while php-sandbox pages show the error message.
The actualy problem is that our error handler is not able to catch this.
What needs to changed to be able to handle such errors?
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class myMaster {
    public $bla;

    private function blubb() {
        $this->bla='blubbaa';
    }

    public function test() {
        $this->blubb();
        return $this->bla;
    }
}

class mySlave extends myMaster{
    protected $bla;

    private function bla() {
        $this->bla='blubbaa';
    }

    public function test2() {
        $this->blubb();
        return $this->bla;
    }
}


https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors: "Note: Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any effect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed."

Essentially, this type off error happens before the script is actually started up, therefore your display_errors command is never executed. You'd be far better to set the error configuration in php.ini rather than in the code.

That means no chance to catch this by set_error_handler() or register_shutdown_function()?So I can only choose between show this also to the user/customer or have a blank page..

You can't do anything in code to catch syntax errors, since the syntax error prevents the code from running.

This sort of startup error should never make it past testing in the first place, so there should be no need to worry about whether a customer sees it. If you're in the habit of putting code with an obvious problem like that straight into a production environment then you might want to have a bit of a review of your development process.

"The actual problem is that our error handler is not able to catch this" - See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8527894/231316. However, also see the top-most comment that alleges to get around this, albeit it in a hacky way: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#112291

Thanks all. It's interesting, when I put display_errors by ini_set in autoprepend file I get the errors displayed. Looks like the autoprepend file is parsed and called independ from the rest. We use the same way to enable/disable opcache.
